# Get location when network isn't available

Tags: java, android, gps, location, android-gps

I am using following code to get location, problem is when there is no network or poor network it stops tracking/ getting location in outdoors, I assume when network isn't there it must switch to GPS only mode and grab location, but it doesn't is there anything else needed ?

```
 try {
        locationManager = (LocationManager) context
                .getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

        // getting GPS status
        isGPSEnabled = locationManager
                .isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);

        // getting network status
        isNetworkEnabled = locationManager
                .isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);

        if (!isGPSEnabled && !isNetworkEnabled) {
            // no network provider is enabled
        } else {
            this.canGetLocation = true;
            // First get location from Network Provider
            if (isNetworkEnabled) {
                locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                        LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER,
                        MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES,
                        MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES, mListener);
                Log.d("Network", "Network");
                if (locationManager != null) {
                    location = locationManager
                            .getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
                    if (location != null) {
                        latitude = location.getLatitude();
                        longitude = location.getLongitude();
                    }
                }
            }
            // if GPS Enabled get lat/long using GPS Services
            if (isGPSEnabled) {
                if (location == null) {


                    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                            LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,
                            MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES,
                            MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES, mListener);
                    Log.d("GPS Enabled", "GPS Enabled");
                    if (locationManager != null) {
                        location = locationManager
                                .getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
                        if (location != null) {
                            latitude = location.getLatitude();
                            longitude = location.getLongitude();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: Have you requested permission for GPS provider?

Comment: @StasLelyuk can you elaborate please ?

Comment: all Location API methods require the ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION or ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION permissions. If your application only has the coarse permission then it will not have access to the GPS or passive location providers.

Comment: @StasLelyuk i have said it in original post that i receive location when there is network , it means i have added permissions already

Comment: So, you've already added FINE_LOCATION permissions?

Comment: @StasLelyuk yes i have

Comment: The `getLastKnownLocation()` method might not always return any location. That's "normal behaviour". You call `locationManager.requestLocationUpdates()` for GPS updates, but have you implemented the `onLocationChanged()` callback to actually receive the location updates that you have requested? At a quick glance it looks you might have based your code on a [code example with well known problems](http://gabesechansoftware.com/location-tracking/).

Comment: @MarkusKauppinen did you see i am already calling requestLoicationUpdates and also implemented onLocationChanged

Comment: @MarkusKauppinen its not like i am not getting location, its working fine until i move to low network coverage or no coverage area , i want GPS to work there